# Program hangs when setting serial port parameters

Tags: c, linux

In my program a connection is opened with serial port that recieves 10-byte packages with set frequency (usually 100 Hz). However i have run into the following problem: sometimes (but not always) when i am closing connection, the program hangs.

In the following code i do not specify constants; at runtime connection parameters (baud rate, parity...) are determined from command line. In practice, connection is usually opened with baud rate 230400, no parity, 8-bit character size and 1 stop bit.

This is how i am opening serial port:

```
struct termios config;
LOGPRINT("Will operate on device \'%s\'\n", pconfig->device);
LOGPRINT("Opening serial device\n");
int flag = O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY;
// pconfig contains some necessary information to set connection parameters
// async == false for connectin that causes problems
int fd = open(pconfig->device, async? flag | O_NONBLOCK: flag);
if(fd == -1)
{ /* skipped error handling */  }

LOGPRINT("Retrieving terminal attributes\n");
if(!!tcgetattr(fd, &config))
{ /* skipped error handling */  }
else
{
    // backup old configuration for restoring it on exit
    if(poldconfig != NULL)
        memcpy(poldconfig, &config, sizeof(struct termios));

    LOGPRINT("Setting terminal attributes\n");
    set_attribs(fd, &config, pconfig);
}
...
int set_attribs(const int fd, struct termios* pterm, const struct serial_config* pconfig)
{
    // set baud rate
    // baud_rates contains integers of actual rates
    LOGPRINT("Setting baud rate to %d.\n", baud_rates[pconfig->baud_rate_index]);
    // change to raw mode
    LOGPRINT("Setting terminal to raw mode\n");
    pterm->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR
                        | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    pterm->c_oflag &= OPOST;
    pterm->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    // baud_bits contains actual pre-defined baud rate flags
    cfsetispeed(pterm, baud_bits[pconfig->baud_rate_index]);
    cfsetospeed(pterm, baud_bits[pconfig->baud_rate_index]);
    LOGPRINT("Set character size, parity and stop bit flags.\n");
    // set character size
    pterm->c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    pterm->c_cflag |= pconfig->csize_flag;
    // set parity
    pterm->c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
    pterm->c_cflag |= pconfig->parity_flag;
    // set stopbits
    pterm->c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    pterm->c_cflag |= pconfig->stopbits_flag;

    // enable reading; ignore control lines
    pterm->c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
    LOGPRINT("Flush terminal.\n");
    // flush terminal
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
    LOGPRINT("Apply parameters.\n");
    return tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, pterm);
}
```

For valid reasons, i needed to force serial device driver to use 1-byte buffer for incoming/outgoing data, which i have set using this function:

```
int set_port_type(int fd, int ptype)
{
    struct serial_struct temp;
    int res = ioctl(fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &temp);
    if(!!res)
    { /* stipped error handling */ }
    temp.type = ptype;
    res = ioctl(fd, TIOCSSERIAL, &temp);
    if(!!res)
    { /* stipped error handling */ }
    return res;
}
```

with ptype = PORT_UNKNOWN or ptype = PORT_16450.

When finished with serial port, i perform the following operations:

1. Flush it
2. Set its type back to 16550A
3. Restore its settigns to saved ones
4. Close it

From time to time it causes the program to hang and stop responding to any external stimulus. It forces me to suspend the program and then reboot system, as it never releases file descriptors it holds.

What can i do to ensure that does not happen? Even if settings are not restored, the program needs to close on its own - maybe with error code.

Operating system i am using is TinyCore Linux. No other user program is being run an the same time as my program.

IMportant clarification. Serial device i am working with is actually NPort 5232 - asyncronous RS-422/485 - Ethernet communicator ([description from vendor](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5210.htm). Consequently, serial devices i am working with are virtual, which enables me to try and change their type / size of internal buffer.

Comment: Presumably, you only close the connection at process termination?  I mean, you don't open and close it at 100Hz?

Comment: Correct; i read from serial device with blocking read() calls in sycle with select(). I close connection when process is being terminated after recieving appropriate signal (i handle SIGINT, to be specific).

Comment: Orite:)  OK, then, what happens when you comment out those closing operations, maybe binary-chop them?

Comment: Also, I dread to think what 'valid reasons' there might be for disabling the FIFO buffer.  You wil get up to 16 times more interrupts:(

Comment: It is better then recieving an interrupt 1/100 of a second late, or so it goes

Comment: this lines: `   if(poldconfig != NULL)
        memcpy(poldconfig, &config, sizeof(struct termios));` is probably wrong,  suggest: `struct termios oldconfig;  memcpy( &oldconfig, &config, sizeof( struct termios) );`

Comment: this line: `int fd = open(pconfig->device, async? flag | O_NONBLOCK: flag);`  `async` is not defined in the posted code

Comment: the use of `!!` just clutters the code,  suggest dropping both of those operators in all instances of their use in the posted code.

Comment: when working with the hardware of a communications port, you cannot change its' type.  I.E. if it is a `16550A` it will always be a `16550A`.  Do not try to change its' type.

Comment: the posted question does not indicate the actual baud rate.  However, of prime importance is Given some baud rate, can the OS (and your program) keep up with it?   are you using interrupts or polling?

Comment: the posted question does not contain enough information on several important areas to enable us to debug your problem.   Some things of interest:  what OS, What else is running, hardware at the actual port, which port driver,  number of bytes in each input burst, baud rate, CPU clock rate, etc etc etc

Comment: user3629249: thank you for comments. I will add clarifications where it is possible

Comment: Assuming you cannot kill the offending process with `kill -KILL pid` either, and looking at the [x86-64 driver](http://www.moxa.com/support/DownloadFile.aspx?type=support&id=952) (latest version from 2012), I'd guess the driver is buggy. (Specifically, in the `close_wait` queue handling.) Not pushing the Linux driver upstream is just stupid, as out of tree drivers are quaranteed to stop working at some point unless actively maintained. (A "stable driver API" would kill the development rate and restrict all changes, so in-tree drivers are the only viable way.)

Comment: When the program hangs, only thing i can do is suspend it and run it to the background (nominally it runs at foreground to be stopped with Ctrl-C at my convenience). After that, i have tried `kill` and attaching with `gdb` - but no changes in the process state were brought about.
As i am not proficient enough to fix the driver myself, i am leaning towards trying to make an `SIGALARM` handler which calls `exit`